# Display different content if window size is below a certain size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I asked this question earlier but wasn't as clear as I should be. Basically I wish to change HTML content (that contains external javascript - see below) depending on windows size/screen res. The question is now changed to better reflect what I need to do. Also I would like this to be done via an external javascript file if possilbe.

I have this code that displays all vertical buttons for sharing my content however I want to display horizontal buttons if the user is using a smaller window size. It will have a different div and some of the code wil be changed i.e. "data-count="horizontal".

It would be awesome to also do this via my external JS file so it is not inline.

But that is not essential.

Thanks in advance.

Also using fluid width CSS is not an option due to my having a sidebar with ads that can't be changed in size and that the html content needs changed - not just CSS.

```
<div id="sharepost">
    <div class="sharer">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-count="vertical" data-via="code_love" data-related="love:code">Tweet</a>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="sharer">
        <a name="fb_share" type="box_count" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>">Share</a>
        <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
    </span>
    </div>
    <div class="sharer">
        <a title="Post on Google Buzz" class="google-buzz-button" href="http://www.google.com/buzz/post" data-button-style="normal-count" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/buzz/api/button.js" defer="defer"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="sharer">
        <script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=3"></script>
    </div>
    <span class="st_email" ></span>
</div>
```

An example of what needs to be done but this doesn't work.

```
   function shareStuff() {

if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
   <div id="sharepost"><div class="sharer"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-count="vertical" data-via="code_love" data-related="love:code">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div>
<div class="sharer"><a name="fb_share" type="box_count" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script></span>
</div><div class="sharer"><a title="Post on Google Buzz" class="google-buzz-button" href="http://www.google.com/buzz/post" data-button-style="normal-count" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/buzz/api/button.js" defer="defer"></script></div><div class="sharer"><script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=3"></script></div><span class="st_email" ></span>
</div>

} else {
  <div id="sharepost"><div class="sharer"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-text="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-count="horizontal" data-via="code_love" data-related="love:code">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div>
<div class="sharer"><a name="fb_share" type="horizontalk" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script></span>
</div><div class="sharer"><a title="Post on Google Buzz" class="google-buzz-button" href="http://www.google.com/buzz/post" data-button-style="normal-count" data-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/buzz/api/button.js" defer="defer"></script></div><div class="sharer"><script src="http://www.stumbleupon.com/hostedbadge.php?s=3"></script></div><span class="st_email" ></span>
</div>
} }
```

Comment: This may or may not be relevant to your question, but you have an unmatched closing span tag in the middle of your markup.  As for your question, what have you done so far?  Where have you gotten stuck?

Comment: That span is used to call a button for email sharing... My earlier question got abandoned because I wasn't clear enough so I'm bascially back to the beginning. No idea what to do. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to do 2 different DIV:

```
<div id="content1"></div>
<div id="content2"></div>
```

now jQuery:

```
$('#content1').hide();
$('#content2').hide();

if(window.width() <= 600) {
    $('#content1').show();
} else {
    $('#content2').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See: http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

Comment: No it's "resolution change content" not just stylesheet. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

[CSSgrid](http://cssgrid.net/) is a project I noticed a week or two ago.  Scales from a static layout for large monitors and becomes fluid down to the smallest of mobile devices.  Seems to solve all your problems!

Comment: Fluid is not an option. I am not looking to change css alone. I want to change HTML too. It's all in my quesiton if you read and also title says "change content if" not change css if.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs/) to switch stylesheets. like this:

```
var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
      path: 'http://yourpath.com/assets/',
      dynamic: true,
      range: [
        '0px    to 480px  = mobile.css',
        '481px  to 840px  = middle.css',
        '841px  to 1440px = large.css',
        '1441px           = xlarge.css'
      ]
    };
```

and then have multiple divs with content:

```
<div id="1440">
BLAH BLAH </div>
<div id="840">
BLEH
</div>
```

then in large.css put this:

```
#840{display:none;}
```

and in middle.css put this

```
#1440{display:none;}
```

baically just use different stylesheets to hide and display content here's a demo:http://adapt.960.gs/test_id.html